# Validating Command Line Args

Tags: perl

My QA guy found an issue in one of my scripts where if he just gave the script garbage as options as a command, my script would still run - but not output anything. For example, if you did  `perl my_script.pl asdf` , it would not print the usage message. I was wondering if there was a way around this besides the **for** loop at the bottom of the example code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;


my $help         = 0;
my $debug        = 0;

my $valid_options = GetOptions(
    'help'           => \$help,
    'debug'          => \$debug,
);

my $file_name = File::Basename::basename($0);
my $usage     = <<"USAGE";
USAGE: perl $file_name [ --help ] [ --debug ]

General Options:
  --help           Displays this help message
  --debug          Show Verbose Debugging Information
USAGE


if ( !$valid_options || $help ) {
    print STDERR $usage;
    exit(1);
}

for my $arg ( @ARGV ) {
    if ( !grep { $_ eq $arg } $valid_options ) {
        print STDERR $usage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my post to clarify: besides the last for loop at the bottom of the script, is there a way to get the script to print the usage message if the script is given garbage as a command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetOptions` function will return false on failure, which you're properly checking with `$valid_options`.

It also removes any values from `@ARGV` that it recognizes, therefore you don't actually have to iterate on the remaining argument array, just check if it contains any values at all.

This is useful since it's often desired to pass a filename to a script, so one would only need to shift off the first element of `@ARGV` after calling `GetOptions` regardless of the order the parameters were passed to the script.

The following therefore shows a simplification of your suggested working script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;

my $valid_options = GetOptions(
    'help'           => \(my $help  = 0),
    'debug'          => \(my $debug = 0),
);

my $file_name = File::Basename::basename($0);
my $usage     = <<"END_USAGE";
USAGE: perl $file_name [ --help ] [ --debug ]

General Options:
  --help           Displays this help message
  --debug          Show Verbose Debugging Information
END_USAGE

die $usage if !$valid_options || $help;

die "Invalid parameter: @ARGV\n$usage" if @ARGV;
```

Comment: Thank You. Probably should have thought of using die. #duh

Answer (score 1):

Your script works for me ...

```
$ ./my_script.pl 
$ ./my_script.pl garbage
USAGE: perl my_script.pl [ --help ] [ --debug ]

General Options:
  --help           Displays this help message
  --debug          Show Verbose Debugging Information
$ ./my_script.pl --help
USAGE: perl my_script.pl [ --help ] [ --debug ]

General Options:
  --help           Displays this help message
  --debug          Show Verbose Debugging Information
$ ./my_script.pl --debug
$ ./my_script.pl --debug garbage
USAGE: perl my_script.pl [ --help ] [ --debug ]

General Options:
  --help           Displays this help message
  --debug          Show Verbose Debugging Information
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I know it works, but I wanted to know if there was a **better** way to make it work than  for looping over @ARGV